# Using a global variable in a for loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

```
for (int i = number_1; i > 0; i--)
{
    int j = 2;
    printf("%*s", i - 1,"");
    for (j; j > 0; j--)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
    j = j + 1;
}
```

Here I'm trying to run my secondary for loop by taking a variable that is declared in the previous loop. It iterates and prints the symbol "#", then gets incremented again by 1 before the outer loop ends.

**I'm getting this error**:

> expression result unused

What's going on here? I can certainly accomplish the task in a different way. But I'd like to find out why the code doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: There is no global variable.

Comment: Is it an error, or is it a warning?

Comment: Perhaps a session with the debugger would be fruitfull

Comment: change `for (j; j > 0; j--)` to `for (; j > 0; j--)`

Comment: What things does not work here?

Comment: After the inner loop is complete, `j` is always zero. And I bet it is not your intention, as you are incrementing it afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

this statement:

```
j = j + 1;
```

gives 'j' a value, but the next iteration through the loop hits this statement:

```
int j = 2;
```

So the results of the first statement are not used.

However, since it is 'initialization', that might not matter.

Then this statement:

```
for (j; j > 0; j--)
```

has an error in the syntax.  Where the first parameter is used to initialize a value, (in this case 'j') but no initialization is performed.

Suggest:

```
for (; j > 0; j--)
```

so the first parameter is omitted

Answer (score 1):

The error is usually only a warning. You have the expression `j;` here:

```
for (j; j > 0; j--)
```

but you don't assign the value of `j` to anything.

Change it to

```
for (; j > 0; j--)
```

And then there is another problem with `j`, as @user3629249 pointed out.
Move the declaration of `j` outside the loop:

```
int j = 2;
for (int i = number_1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%*s", i - 1,"");
        for (; j > 0; j--)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
        j = j + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

change to

```
for (int i = number_1, j = 2; i > 0; i--, ++j)//j move to this. 
{
    printf("%*s", i - 1,"");
    for (int k = j; k > 0; k--)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```